# How can i include the top part of my generated outline?

Tags: c#, image-processing

Whenever I try to generate an outline, the bottom part of the outline always generates correctly, the top part however does not.

I think this is due to ySouth being true, but I don't know how to fix it.

this is the code:

```
private Bitmap HollowOut(Bitmap contour)
{
    Bitmap returnMap = contour;
    for (int y = 0; y < contour.Height; y++)
    {
        // FINDING BLACK PIXEL
        for (int x = 0; x < contour.Width; x++)
        {
            Color pixelColour = contour.GetPixel(x, y);
            int combinedRGB = (pixelColour.R + pixelColour.G + pixelColour.B);

            if (combinedRGB == 0)
            {
                for (int i = x + 1; i < contour.Width; i++)
                {
                    pixelColour = contour.GetPixel(i, y);
                    combinedRGB = (pixelColour.R + pixelColour.G + pixelColour.B);
                    if (combinedRGB > 0)
                    {
                        // CHECKING X WALLTHICKNESS
                        if ((i - x) > (wallThickness * 2))
                        {
                            int startOfRectangle = x;
                            int endOfRectangle = i;

                            // REMOVING EXCESS BLACK PIXELS
                            for (int j = startOfRectangle + wallThickness; j < endOfRectangle - (wallThickness); j++)
                            {
                                // CHECKING Y WALLTHICKNESS
                                // CHECK NORTH
                                bool yNorth = false;
                                Color pixelColor = contour.GetPixel(j, y - wallThickness);
                                combinedRGB = pixelColor.R + pixelColor.G + pixelColor.B;
                                if (combinedRGB == 0)
                                {
                                    yNorth = true;
                                }
                                // CHECK SOUTH
                                bool ySouth = false;
                                pixelColor = contour.GetPixel(j, y + wallThickness);
                                combinedRGB = pixelColor.R + pixelColor.G + pixelColor.B;
                                if (combinedRGB == 0)
                                {
                                    ySouth = true;
                                }

                                if (yNorth || ySouth)
                                    returnMap.SetPixel(j, y, Color.White);
                            }
                            x = i;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            x = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return returnMap;
}
```

I have tried to make the OR statement for the making of white pixels an AND and XOR gate, but both created weird artifacts.

I would appreciate any help i can get.